# golang SDK - increase limit - more than 10 results on client.ClaimableBalances

Tags: go-sdk

How can I set horizonclient to return more than 10 results?

```
client := horizonclient.DefaultPublicNetClient //live

balances, err := client.ClaimableBalances(horizonclient.ClaimableBalanceRequest{
    Asset: "AQUA:GBNZILSTVQZ4R7IKQDGHYGY2QXL5QOFJYQMXPKWRRM5PAV7Y4M67AQUA",
}
```

This will only return 10 results.  The limit for horizon is 200; how can I increase the limit?  Also, for paging, how can I set the page?

Answer (score 0):

The feature does not yet exist.  I made a feature request here: https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/4246 and a pull request (fix) for the feature: https://github.com/stellar/go/pull/4248/commits/3d84568c8b94d83288887685f6503f5dfd455c64 , so if you want this feature to work on your local and this is not merged yet, you can just pull it into your local repo of the stellar go sdk.